# CommunicationException in client-service integration test

Tags: c#, wcf, integration-testing, azure-pipelines

I'm making an integration tests for my WCF service, in which my test client is making requests to self hosted service.

My WCF service setup:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding {Security = {Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport}};
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:44398/MyService.svc");
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), endpointAddress.Uri);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfServices.Contracts.IMyService),
binding, endpointAddress.Uri);
host.Open();
```

And my client call:

```
var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);

// Act

Contract.MyResult result;
try
{
    result = actMethod.Invoke(sut);
}
finally
{
    client.Close();
    if (host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
        host.Close();
    else
        host.Abort();
}
```

Before executing tests, I run this PowerShell script:

```
$whoami = WHOAMI
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:44398/MyService.svc/ user=$whoami
```

Everything works just fine on my local machines, but when it's built with my pipeline in Azure DevOps, and it comes to running this particular test, I get:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException : An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:44398/MyService.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
>
> ---- System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> -------- System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> ------------ System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Also, I've tried adding this to my test:

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol == (SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls))
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Without any change.

I get that it may have something to do with the fact I've never used any certificate in pipeline, though I wonder why would it work without one on my local machine then. Also, I don't really know how to properly set up one in pipeline. Could someone give me a hand with solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that config is specified properly with the below tags,

```
<serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="nameofBehaviour">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

In addition, you can try adding the below lines in your code.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
 System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
   System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | Tls1.1 | Tls1.0
```

Comment: Sadly, nothing has changed, still same exception.

Comment: could try with self-signed certificates !

Comment: I've issued one with `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "https://localhost:44398/MyService.svc/" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"` in build process, but to no avail. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: DnsName should be localhost. And you should bind it to the port on the build machine. You can also check with `net http show sslcert` which certificate is bound on your local machine.